# Instagram Creator Studio not loading video to post

Tags: facebook, instagram

Just recently the creator studio for Instagram keeps throwing an error when i try to upload a video. It will not pass 0% and will be in red. I tried everything from different browsers, computers and accounts. Not sure what else to do or if anyone else is facing the same issue.

[image]

Comment: Happens to me too. Just as a note, this behaviour now shows up also for videos I added successfully in the past. So it is not a format or encoding issue, unless changed on IG side.

Comment: Were you able to post currently?

Comment: No, the situation to not be able to post videos is since 2-3 weeks at least and still bad.

Comment: Ya its been over 2 weeks for me now, is there another site you use to schedule posts for instagram?

Comment: There is some desktop software I use now (e.g. Grids on Mac). The problem is, per post there is only one video possible with these, I usually posta carousel with two vids.

Comment: is it free to use?

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of no answers, neither here nor officially, the issue is actually solved, as Facebook / Instagram released a a new business suite capable of posting videos again.